# Unable to Build Gradle as Make Project

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar, android-support-library

i am trying to Call Support v7 and v4 with version 28.0.0  and it shows build error

like

```
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha1)
```

i have tried with 28.0.0 and 28.0.3 as well as 28.0.0-alpha1  and

android.useAndroidX=false
android.enableJetifier=false

tries for true/false both not able to find any solution to Run My Project App

Answer (score 0):

Try out removing unnecessary support library from SDK

Comment: No, am asking about the suport library in SDK, Open SDK manager in Android Studio and try removing unnecessary support library from there and see if it works.

Comment: if still not working try removing "-alpha1" in build.gradle(app module) dependency (try changing "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0-alpha1" into "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0") .